# How do I specify TAP::Harness::Junit in the perl makefile?

Tags: perl, makefile

I have a Makefile.PL using MakeMaker for my perl module like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use 5.008;

use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile
(
    NAME          => 'MyModule',
    AUTHOR        => 'Subu',
    LICENSE       => 'perl',
    PREREQ_PM     => {
        'File::Basename' => '0',
    },
    TEST_REQUIRES => {
        'Test::More'       => '0.47',
        'Test::MockModule' => 'v0.170.0',
        'Test::MockObject' => '1.20180705',
        'Devel::Cover'     => '1.31',
        'Test::File'       => '1.443'
    },
    BUILD_REQUIRES => {
        'Log::Log4perl'  => '1.49',
        'JSON::Parse'    => '0.55',
        'Time::Piece'    => '1.33',
        'Text::CSV'      => '1.97'
    },
    EXE_FILES => [
        'src/main/perl/MyModule/main.pl'
    ],

    test => {TESTS => 'src/test/perl/MyModule/*/*.t 
src/test/perl/MyModule/*/*/*.t'}

);
```

I'm able to run tests using

```
perl Makefile.PL
make 
make test
```

However, I would like to have the output formatted using the TAP::Harness::Junit. How do I specify that in the makefile ?

I know I can run the tests with prove

```
prove --formatter TAP::Formatter::JUnit *.t
```

But I wanted to know if there is a way I can plug that into my makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Makefile.PL` is primarily intended to make your modules cpan-installable. For example, `make test` would be run during module installation to verify that it works correctly on the target system. For that purpose, changing the formatter (and adding an extra dependency) is not helpful.

The `Makefile.PL` is not necessarily the place for your personal development workflow or for any Continuous Integration scripts. E.g. if you want to generate JUnit test reports on a Jenkins server, you might want to put the `prove --formatter TAP::Formatter::JUnit *.t` command into a Jenkinsfile. If you prefer writing Makefiles, you could use a separate Makefile for your personal development scipts, though you'd have to use `make -f MyMakefile test` to invoke it.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.